# How to send data from Android phone to PC in continuous stream manner via USB connection(just send whenever available )

Tags: android, data-transfer, libusb

I am developing an application in which some data should be available from phone to PC as soon as its available in phone(e.g. user types something in app or user press at some coordinate in app and App record the coordinate but we need to pass the coordinates to PC).
The data may be string of character ,integers etc.

Actually we can pass data in "save and send " manner where I can run adb pull command to get data but it's not desirable.
  Because we have some simulator app at PC which need the data just in time when it's produced at phone side.

So its should be like continuous streaming from device to PC(PC may be windows,linux or nay other OS)...

It's  also acceptable if we can just update some data file which is  at PC's harddisk just in time manner whenever new data available at phone so that simulator can read new changes and act accordingly.

I searched a lot in internet and what I can find is as below:

adb shell port-forward

adb shell ppp

I found port-forward somewhat related to this task but I am not quite sure if it will be  useful and am I going in right direction?

Also if port-forward option is right to do the task,do I require to write client application for socket connection at PC side and also at phone side in app?

I would appreciate your efforts.

Thanks..

Comment: There is one more development/finding in this regard from my side.Using port forwarding,I am able to send message from PC to phone. But I need exactly opposite behavior i.e. able to send message from phone to PC . To do this,I server socket code on phone(android app) and client socket code (a java program) on PC .

Comment: I tried to do do opposite communication by writing server socket code on PC(Java  app) and client socket code on Phone but it does not work and says port is busy after running adb forward command. Is it not possible to do Phone to PC communication using adb port forward?

Comment: Below is the logs:                                                                       /ProjectSetupData/install/jre1.6.0_45/bin$ java GreetingServer 6069
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at GreetingServer.<init>(GreetingServer.java:12)
 at GreetingServer.main(GreetingServer.java:51)

Comment: If I dont run ad forward before server program execution,client on deviec does not connect.

Comment: I got the success after trying many times using scoket connection with port-forwarding .

Comment: Can you share your code, plz?